# Identify isometric geometric parameter

Tags: differential-geometry

For a  planar curve y=f(x) (primes with respect to x ) identify the third order isometric invariant:

$$ y^{'''} - \dfrac{3 y^{'} y^{ ''2}}{(1 + y^{'^{2}}) }  \tag 1 $$

and find curves when this invariant

- vanishes, and when it
- is a constant.

EDIT1:

Obtained by differentiation to eliminate 3 arbitrary constants in:

$$ (x - C_1)^2 + ( y - C_2)^2 = C_3 \tag 2 $$

EDIT2:

Due to elimination of Euclidean motions and radius  $ C_3$ it must be/related to an isometric invariant of a curve.

EDIT3:

Integrating when it vanishes, we get differential equation of a circle.

$$ y^{''} = (1+ y^{'2})^{3/2} * const. \tag 3 $$ 
EDIT 4:

We can state this with respect to tangent rotation $\phi$ as well:

$$ \tan \phi = \frac{dy}{dx},  \kappa = \frac{d\phi}{ds} \tag4, $$ then a constant $ \kappa $ is a circle and $ \dfrac{d \kappa}{ds}$ is valid for Cornu's Spiral (Clothoid).

So what different expression similar to $(1)$ can express constant rate of curvature change?

Answer (score 0):

The term $$\Theta(x):=y'''-{3y'y''^2\over1+y'^2}$$ occurs in the following environment: Given a curve $\gamma: \>x\mapsto y(x)$ in the plane one has
$$\kappa'(x)={1\over\bigl(1+y'^2(x)\bigr)^{3/2}}\Theta(x)\ .\tag{1}$$
Therefore, if $\Theta(x)\equiv0$ then the curvature $\kappa$ is constant along $\gamma$; whence $\gamma$ is (part of) a circle. When $\Theta(x)\equiv C\ne0$ then $(1)$ says
$$\kappa'(x)={C\over s'^3(x)}\  ,\tag{2}$$
where $x\mapsto s(x)$ denotes arc length along $\gamma$. I don't think that $(2)$ has a "geometrically invariant" meaning.

Comment: @ Christian Blatter: I had seen something similar to it in Differential Geometry book by HW Guggenheimer.